# After updating Ionic node npm, I am having trouble running Dezalgo

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\2bher>npm install -g ionic@latest
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'asap’
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\dezalgo\dezalgo.js:4:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions…js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
module.js:471
throw err;
^

C:\Users\2bher>ionic -v

? The Ionic CLI has an update available (3.9.2 => 3.12.0)! Would you like to install it? (Y/n)
C:\Users\2bher>y

C:\Users\2bher>ionic -v

? The Ionic CLI has an update available (3.9.2 => 3.12.0)! Would you like to install it? Yes

npm install -g ionic@latest
| Running command
C:\Users\2bher>
jumping to empty command line without installing the update

C:\Users\2bher>node -v
v6.9.5

C:\Users\2bher>npm -v
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module ‘asap’
```

My package.json

```
{
“name”: “ionic3-angular4”,
“version”: “0.0.1”,
“author”: “Ionic Framework”,
“homepage”: “http://ionicframework.com/”,
“private”: true,
“scripts”: {
“clean”: “ionic-app-scripts clean”,
“build”: “ionic-app-scripts build”,
“lint”: “ionic-app-scripts lint”,
“ionic:build”: “ionic-app-scripts build”,
“ionic:serve”: “ionic-app-scripts serve”
},
“dependencies”: {
"@angular/common": “4.1.3”,
"@angular/compiler": “4.1.3”,
"@angular/compiler-cli": “4.1.3”,
"@angular/core": “4.1.3”,
"@angular/forms": “4.1.3”,
"@angular/http": “4.1.3”,
"@angular/platform-browser": “4.1.3”,
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": “4.1.3”,
"@ionic-native/camera": “3.12.1”,
"@ionic-native/core": “3.10.2”,
"@ionic-native/device": “^4.0.0”,
"@ionic-native/geolocation": “^4.2.1”,
"@ionic-native/google-maps": “3.12.1”,
"@ionic-native/native-storage": “^4.0.0”,
"@ionic-native/network": “^4.2.1”,
"@ionic-native/social-sharing": “^4.1.0”,
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": “3.10.2”,
"@ionic-native/status-bar": “3.10.2”,
"@ionic/cloud-angular": “^0.12.0”,
"@ionic/storage": “2.0.1”,
"@ngx-translate/core": “6.0.1”,
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": “0.0.3”,
"@types/google-maps": “^3.2.0”,
“copyfiles”: “^1.2.0”,
“cordova-android”: “^6.2.3”,
“cordova-browser”: “^4.1.0”,
“cordova-plugin-compat”: “^1.0.0”,
“cordova-plugin-console”: “^1.0.5”,
“cordova-plugin-device”: “^1.1.4”,
“cordova-plugin-facebook4”: “^1.9.1”,
“cordova-plugin-geolocation”: “^2.4.3”,
“cordova-plugin-googlemaps”: “git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps.git#multiple_maps”,
“cordova-plugin-inappbrowser”: “^1.7.1”,
“cordova-plugin-nativestorage”: “^2.2.2”,
“cordova-plugin-network-information”: “^1.3.3”,
“cordova-plugin-splashscreen”: “^4.0.3”,
“cordova-plugin-statusbar”: “^2.2.2”,
“cordova-plugin-whitelist”: “^1.3.1”,
“cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing”: “^5.1.8”,
“es6-promise-plugin”: “^4.1.0”,
“ionic-angular”: “3.4.2”,
“ionic-plugin-keyboard”: “^2.2.1”,
“ionicons”: “3.0.0”,
“rxjs”: “5.4.0”,
“sw-toolbox”: “3.6.0”,
“zone.js”: “0.8.12”
},
“devDependencies”: {
"@ionic/app-scripts": “1.3.7”,
"@types/googlemaps": “^3.26.20”,
“ionic”: “3.10.3”,
“typescript”: “2.3.3”
},
“description”: “An Ionic project”,
“cordova”: {
“plugins”: {
“cordova-plugin-console”: {},
“cordova-plugin-device”: {},
“cordova-plugin-splashscreen”: {},
“cordova-plugin-statusbar”: {},
“cordova-plugin-whitelist”: {},
“ionic-plugin-keyboard”: {},
“cordova-plugin-facebook4”: {
“APP_ID”: “150689565500190”,
“APP_NAME”: “Wise-App”
},
“cordova-plugin-nativestorage”: {},
“cordova-plugin-inappbrowser”: {},
“cordova-plugin-googlemaps”: {
“API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID”: “AIzaSyAa3AAitzhvZ6rHHGkvZwO-v6gHzRiNung”,
“API_KEY_FOR_IOS”: “AIzaSyC9Q0pSTFtoK0kQ0yKrnSTrKAH9vylAoqs”
},
“cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing”: {},
“cordova-plugin-geolocation”: {},
“cordova-plugin-network-information”: {}
},
“platforms”: [
“android”,
“browser”
]
}
}
```

How can I restore the working running solution?

I need to say that as my project grows the amount of time it takes me to make the project run and debug is grows exponentially. It becomes more than the programming time!

(I am debugging with Cordova tools).